# Python: what does self.control in a subclass of wx.Frame mean?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am following the Getting started with wxPython tutorial, to [this part](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#First_steps). What is `control` in the following line? I have searched in the `Frame` [class reference](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html) and googled for a while but still no clue.

```
self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

Just in case next time I need information like this, where should I look?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found it from [The Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html)

> To create instance variables, they can be set in a method with `self.name = value`

So, control is just an instance variable, no more no less.